# How to animate button at startup

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, button

I am doing a startup button which prompts the user to click it at the start.

I would like to animate my button at startup, with the animation of the button mouseover and mouseout continuously so that it looks like its blinking. And then stop animating it when it is clicked.

Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main storyboard would be instigated by the Loaded event of the button. Then you would have another event trigger on the Click event which removes the storyboard created in the Loaded event.

For example:

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
        </Button.Background>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="MainStoryboard">
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Duration="00:00:02" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <ColorAnimation To="Black" AutoReverse="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MainStoryboard"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
        Test
    </Button>
```